# import serial doesnot work in python

Tags: php, python, serial-port, hex

I had installed `pyserial` 2.5 and my python version is 3.2.1 when I try to import serial it show the option but when I run the same program got error`ImportError: No module named serial` and my editor is `aptana studio` is there any better solution to send hex data to serial port by using either `python` or `PHP`

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to import serial it show the option"?

Comment: Have you tried to run the program outside of Aptana?

Comment: is it necessary to check. Got an error of syntax error

Comment: How did you get a syntax error? Please add full traceback to the question.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\serialport\examples\enhancedserial.py", line 14, in <module>
    from serial import Serial
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from serialwin32 import *
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 12, in <module>
    import win32
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\serial\win32.py", line 164
    MAXDWORD = 4294967295L # Variable c_uint
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`Error from a example pyserial 2.6 and all above are indicates from import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have installed Pyserial by unzipping it directly to your site-packages folder.

If you instead install it by

```
python3 setup.py install
```

setup.py will convert the files to be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: I had tried to install it but got some error below is stack trace
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python32\pyserial-2.6\setup.py", line 44, in <module>
    open(os.path.join('serial', '__init__.py')).read()).group(1)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serial\\__init__.py'` but the file `__init__.py` is there

Comment: @madan Did you CD to the directory where setup.py is?

Comment: thank u  very much it works for me and I am able to print image through rs232

Answer (score 0):

Pyserial website says v2.5 works up to py 3.1
v2.6 shows that it works up to py 3.2 .. have you tried that yet?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Comment: indeed I did ... extra text

Comment: i had tried the given examples in the `pyserial 2.0.6` and getting the error from there only